# Setting PageSize of Google Slides with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-slides-api

I am creating google slides with the help of javascript API. I need to set up the page size But its not working. Below is my code .

```
        var size = {
              width:{
                magnitude: 612,
                unit: "PT"
              },
             height: {
                magnitude: 792,
                unit: 'PT'
            }};

gapi.client.slides.presentations.create({
        title: "Some title",
        pageSize: size
        }).then((response) => {
     var presentationId = response.result.presentationId;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Method: presentations.create](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create)

> Creates a new presentation using the title given in the request. Other
>   fields in the request are ignored. Returns the created presentation.

Here is the [request body](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create#request-body):

```
{
  "presentationId": string,
  "pageSize": {
    object(Size)
  },
  "slides": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "title": string,
  "masters": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "layouts": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "locale": string,
  "revisionId": string,
  "notesMaster": {
    object(Page)
  },
}
```

To check the description of `pageSize`, you can refer to the fields table. It was specified as the [size](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/Size) of pages in the presentation.

Also, you may want to check this [javascript Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/javascript) to help you further.